# SEO SERP Google Chrome App

Tags: google-workspace, search-results

Has anyone installed 'SEO SERP' from Omiod app in chrome?

If so, how accurate would you rate it?

So far I'm thinking its pretty good, but I have never tried any paid versions.

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on this one?